# How to make a variable hold a maximum amount of arguments

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I don't know much. My goal is to make a calculator that asks how many arguments you want to multiply together. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. I made a very beta version of this

```
nums = []

class mathFunc():
    

    def multiply():
        f = input("How many arguments: ")
        argz = float(f)

        while argz>0:
            argz = argz - 1
            nums.append(argz)
        ##################
        length = len(nums)
        print(length)
mathFunc.multiply()
```

Does anyone have any tips? Please lmk!

Comment: Why are you using a `class` here? If `multiply` is a class method, you're missing a `self` argument. If that's supposed to be a static class method, you're missing a decorator. `multiply` might as well be a standalone function.

Comment: "Number of arguments" should not be a float.  It is an integer.  If you want to input N arguments, then you should be using `input` in your loop, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

The simple mechanism is just to ask for numbers until they hit "enter" to stop entering numbers:

```
def multiply():
    product = 1
    while 1:
        f = input("What's the next number? ")
        if f == '':
            return product
        product *= float(f)
        print("Total so far is", product)
print(multiply())
```